# spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others not working for me to disable access

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am trying to set spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false so that the console is only available on the local machine. It works great if I run my application in IntelliJ, but as soon as I build  the jar and run it, this setting seems to have no effect and defaults to enabled.

I don't believe I have any parameters being passed to the jar at startup, but I'm wondering if something else can override this settings.

So I have the following in my application.properties.

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
#spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
```

As this example shows it's commented out, which I expect to be default to false. I have tried uncommenting and setting to false, but no effect.
I have tried using the H2 normal config value of webAllowOthers, but no effect.

If I set spring.h2.console.enabled=false, I no longer am able to access the console.  I feel this shows that I'm at least editing the correct file.

I do have a secondary test.properties used by our test cases, but i have tried setting to false and removing in that file as well.  I had thought that maybe last one in wins or something.

I'm at a loss of other things to try, my only thought is a bug or some other config that can override these settings.

I am using SpringBoot 2.0.0.RELEASE AND dB2 1.4.196

UPDATE:  Upon further testing, it seems like it works fine if I build the jar and have console enabled and web-allow-others disabled.  But once I enabled web-allow-others once, it never blocks it again, even after web-allow-others=false

Answer (score 2):

Add below bean in your code and open http://remoteIp:8080/ and it will work

```
    @Bean(initMethod="start",destroyMethod="stop")
public org.h2.tools.Server h2WebConsoleServer () throws SQLException {
    return org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer("-web","-webAllowOthers","-webDaemon","-webPort", "8080");
}
```

Comment: I didn't have any luck with this.  It appears with further testing that it works great as compiled.  If webAllowOthers is false, it does not allow.  I then edit the application.properties in the folder witht he jar, and as soon as I do that it's enabled, and always stays enabled

Answer (score 1):

This frustrated me as well.

It looks like, upon a successful login to the console, H2 saves the settings in a local 'settings file'.  For my Linux system the file was $HOME/.h2.server.properties.

In that file it had recorded 'webAllowOthers=true', which seemed to take precedence over any application.properties files.

After removing the file things worked as expected, honouring the application.properties settings.